# Shortcuts to write into keyboard buffer

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Has anyone come across a good Windows application (for Win10 environment) to emulate USB keyboard key strokes?

I have used an USB barcode scanner to scan a barcode and add appropriate commands as barcode string prefix and suffix, but could there be a application that would do this without a scanner?

Something to the like of:

Pressing Ctrl+Y results a sequence of keypresses, like: `Enter + Ctrl-A + Enter + Tab + ...` whatever. The string of commands could even be longer, but hopefully with configurable pace.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a program like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) that can programmatically create a vast selection of keyboard shortcuts, macros and well pretty much anything you can do with a keyboard, mouse and beyond.

There is a very good documentation and an extensive community built around it.

For example the requested shortcut would be:

Autohotkey.ahk:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

; ^ is Ctrl
^y::Send {Enter}^A{Enter}{Tab}...
```